# No changes detected for makemigrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I am new to Django. I want to create tables by using models.
I have tried to follow this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/.

I have registered the app and provided connection details of the DB.

But when I tried to run makemigrations and migrate, it's not identifying the changes.
python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: have you specify the app name in settings.py in installed_app list

Answer (score 0):

For a new app, one without any migrations, you must first create an initial migration file. This can be done by passing the app name to `makemigrations`

```
python manage.py makemigrations app
```

[Here is the relevant section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations)

> To add migrations to an app that doesn’t have a migrations directory, run makemigrations with the app’s app_label